# How to add custom Play/ pause buttons, volume bar etc in MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, custom-controls, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to create a player like in a image below, starting from play and pause button. but it's not showing up on a player. how can i create customize panel for my player, custom bar, volume bar etc?

```
- (IBAction)playMovie:(UIButton *)sender {

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlStr.text];
self.movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
self.movie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

self.movie.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.movie.view];
[self.movie setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

playButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100)];
[playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:playButton];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add player on a view with button like your image describes

```
    moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlVideo];
    [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 270)];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController play];// put it in action
```

Comment: Hello, Where is the button on a video, i want to add a custom pause button on a video.

Comment: add button on that view where you'll add the MPMoviePlayerController